# PhotoEditor SDK Crash on Android 6.0

Tags: android, photoeditorsdk

I have integrated photoeditor SDK into my android application, but application gets crashed while clicking on export/save button of photoeditor SDK.
Below is the crash logs.

```
-15526/com.picedit.app.debug E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
04-19 14:40:58.208 15526-15526/com.picedit.app.debug E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
04-19 14:40:58.217 15526-15526/com.picedit.app.debug E/ANR_LOG: >>> msg's executing time is too long
04-19 14:40:58.217 15526-15526/com.picedit.app.debug E/ANR_LOG: Blocked msg = { when=-1s658ms what=110 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{883af87 com.picedit.app.debug}} } , cost  = 1642 ms
04-19 14:40:58.217 15526-15526/com.picedit.app.debug E/ANR_LOG: >>>Current msg List is:
04-19 14:40:58.217 15526-15526/com.picedit.app.debug E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <1>  = { when=-1s657ms what=100 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=ActivityRecord{8f70eb4 token=android.os.BinderProxy@ae44add {com.picedit.app.debug/ly.img.android.ui.activities.CameraPreviewActivity}} }
04-19 14:40:58.217 15526-15526/com.picedit.app.debug E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <2>  = { when=-1s253ms what=149 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=android.os.BinderProxy@ae44add }
04-19 14:40:58.217 15526-15526/com.picedit.app.debug E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <3>  = { when=-3ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=ly.img.android.authorization.a.a$1 }
04-19 14:40:58.217 15526-15526/com.picedit.app.debug E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <4>  = { when=+9s962ms what=132 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H }
04-19 14:40:58.217 15526-15526/com.picedit.app.debug E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <5>  = { when=+59s995ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcfq }
04-19 14:40:58.217 15526-15526/com.picedit.app.debug E/ANR_LOG: >>>CURRENT MSG DUMP OVER<<<
04-19 14:40:58.225 15526-15583/com.picedit.app.debug V/FA: Connecting to remote service
04-19 14:40:58.233 15526-15526/com.picedit.app.debug V/FA: onActivityCreated
04-19 14:40:58.250 15526-15583/com.picedit.app.debug V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
04-19 14:40:58.337 15526-15526/com.picedit.app.debug E/CheckPermission: camera-code= 1
04-19 14:40:58.337 15526-15526/com.picedit.app.debug V/Camera: current package %scom.picedit.app.debug
04-19 14:40:58.337 15526-15526/com.picedit.app.debug E/Camera-JNI: shield numberOfCameras 2
04-19 14:40:58.487 15526-15526/com.picedit.app.debug V/RenderScript_jni: RS native mode
04-19 14:40:58.500 15526-15526/com.picedit.app.debug V/RenderScript_jni: Unable to load libRSSupportIO.so, USAGE_IO not supported
04-19 14:40:58.501 15526-15526/com.picedit.app.debug V/RenderScript_jni: Unable to load BLAS lib, ONLY BNNM will be supported: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.picedit.app.debug-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libblasV8.so"
04-19 14:40:58.604 15526-15588/com.picedit.app.debug V/RenderScript: 0x7f8622c000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 8
04-19 14:40:58.633 15526-15588/com.picedit.app.debug V/RenderScript: Successfully loaded runtime: libRSDriver_adreno.so
04-19 14:40:58.679 15526-15526/com.picedit.app.debug I/Background: getBackgroundColor [0.0; 0.0; 0.0; 1.0; ]
04-19 14:40:58.681 15526-15526/com.picedit.app.debug E/CheckPermission: camera-code= 3
```

Comment: *`but application get crashed`*   Where is your **`Crash-Log`** share Crash log with question

Comment: The last line says `CheckPermission: camera-code= 3` Do you have proper permissions? I am having a similar issue, It just restarts the RN app without completely saving the image in location.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any helpfull information in this log, because there is no crash logged.
But, please check if you have defined the correct RenderScript version in you application gradle file.

```
    renderscriptTargetApi 23
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

Please try also to clean the build folder, delete the app from your test device and do a fresh installation.
There is sometimes a bug in some Android Versions, that the RenderScripts are not recompiled while updating an installed debug version. This can cause a native crash.